# How do you remove or even get to the car battery on a 2012 Honda Odyssey?

Tags: electrical, honda, battery

### Summary

> How do you get to the battery on a 2012 Honda Odyssey, given that it is blocked by some type of intake tube**?

**Edit: this used to say *exhaust* but I changed it to *intake tube*, given the answers, below.

### Details

We have a new 2012 Honda Odyssey and our old car battery just died. So I'm trying to give it a jump but the Odyssey's battery is blocked by something that I can't remove.

Does anyone know how to remove these fastener/screw things (at the bottom of the picture below)? I've tried turning them as well as prying them with a butter knife. The red terminal is accessible but the black one is completely blocked by this thing.  I need to get to both to jump my car.

[image: Battery blocked by something I cannot get off]

Comment: You can also attach the ground (negative) to the engine block for jump starting.

Comment: Yes, if I needed to jump start this car, that would work. Unfortunately, I need to use this car as the "good battery" to jump another car. As far as I know, that requires connecting to both terminals.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. It requires both terminals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, unless there's something special about Honda Odysseys, it doesn't require both battery terminals actually.

When I say I'm "pretty sure" I mean I have done this multiple times with my BMW, where the battery is in the boot.

Comment: I'm with @SamJones. It is conventional to connect the "good" battery at both terminals, and it definitely helps avoid connection problems, but you should be able to use any suitable grounding point on the "good" car in place of the battery negative post. That's what I'd try first if my car looked like yours.

Comment: Have you tried looking around for a remote "black terminal", or another location specially labeled to show that it's intended to be used as the negative post in a jump start?  Of course, there's always the friendly manual.

Comment: @Iszi: There is indeed an auxiliary negative (ground) terminal lug nut in the engine chassis for this purpose.

Comment: Glad this worked! One of the implications here is that the vehicle with the good battery both connections must be directly to the battery. Why is that? If you find a place that is a "good" ground, where good means capable of carrying a lot of current, why can't you use engine block or other good grounds for this? In the end, all good grounds lead to the negative terminal, so why is access to the actual negative terminal required? Having jumped many a car over the years, I've never had an issue going with engine grounds on both ends. Am I missing something?

Comment: Tangential answer: To jump start another vehicle with your 2012 Odyssey ***you don't need to remove anything*** to access the battery terminals. The positive terminal has a cap to flip up. The negative terminal, with a solid metal bar, is accessible if you look carefully on the other side of the air intake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to sneak a clamp on to the positive terminal, and there's an auxiliary negative (ground) terminal lug nut to clamp onto right in front of the coolant fill tube and power steering fluid reservoir.

[image: odysseybattery]

Otherwise if you really want more room, you need to remove the intake tube (nothing to do with *exhaust*) by disconnecting it at the rubber snorkel attached to the throttle body. Loosen any hose clamps on it, and use some force to pry it loose the first time. It might be stubborn, but just keep wiggling!

Comment: @BobCross: Found the picture on a forum somewhere, so can't take full credit for that :)

Comment: Looks like I don't have enough reputation to upvote :)
I just want to confirm that this solution works. Today I jump-started an old Lexus (with dead battery) using a Honda Odyssey 2014 (with good battery). You can use the +ve of the (good) battery and the (-ve) bolt (Shown in picture) on the car's body.

Comment: see also [How to Jumpstart a 2011-2017 Honda Odyssey](https://www.carcarekiosk.com/video/2011_Honda_Odyssey_EX-L_3.5L_V6/battery/jump_start) (tutorial with videos) and [How to jumpstart a Honda Odyssey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHMQHThNTsQ) (short video with reference to the ground screw)

Answer (score 5):

To answer the actual question of "how to remove these fastener/screw things":  Use a flat head screwdriver to pop out the inner, smaller circle thing.  Once that is done, you can use your fingers to pick up the outer circle thing.  Then grab hold of the entire air intake box and wiggle it free of the rubber sleeve/seal and the entire thing will come of cleanly and give a lot of room to get at the battery.  Good Luck.

Comment: On our 2013 Odyssey these plastic bolts look different. They're in the same locations on the air intake, but they have a philips head. If you try to loosen them with a philips screwdriver they loosen to a point that they just turn but they won't come loose. Any idea on how to remove these to get to the battery?

Comment: Here is a video showing the fastener removal: https://youtu.be/0QDHOplrGsc?t=106